# Symfony3 - How to validate HTML tags

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x, symfony-validator

By using Symfony validators
How to prevent some HTML tags like 
`<input></input>` `<textarea><textarea>`
from being entered in input field and saved in database?

Comment: When you say "some HTML tags" do you mean all HTML tags or specific ones?

Comment: @OKsure, I mean only specific ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assert using regex on text/string properties in your entity. For example, this should block any HTML tags in a string:

```
// src/Entity/Thing.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Thing
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i",
     *     match=false,
     *     message="Your text cannot contain HTML"
     * )
     */
    protected $text;
}
```

This should check for input and textarea elements:

```
// src/Entity/Thing.php
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Thing
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/<(?=.*? .*?\/ ?>|textarea|input)[a-z]+.*?>|<([a-z]+).*?<\/\1>/i",
     *     match=false,
     *     message="Your text cannot contain certain HTML tags"
     * )
     */
    protected $text;
}
```

Comment: As per the HTML spec (w3.org), tag name can tonain 0-9,a-z,A-Z and a solidus character "/" before the >. Your regex wouldn't catch the ones that start with 0-9, if there may be in the future? Just a quick observation.

Answer (score 0):

also you can use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) php function in your setter function to prevent html tags, also you can pass some allowed tags to this function.

```
public function setText()
{
    $this->text = strip_tags($text);
    return $this;
}
```